# Creating different sets of variables, and assigning them using if else

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a set of variables. And for different scenarios, I would like to use a different set. So I was wondering if there is a way of doing so without using the `if-else` statement? Below is what I am trying to achieve using the `if-else` approach:

```
if(broker=="A"){
  brokeragefutures=aaaa
  brokerageoptions=bbbb
  STT=cccc

} 
else if(broker=="B"){
  brokeragefutures=xxxx
  brokerageoptions=yyyy
  STT=zzzz
}
  ....
  ....


  ....
}
```

So in the end, I would just use the broker name and the variables will automatically be used for my computations. This would make trying different scenarios very easy.

My question is, is there a more efficient way of doing this, than by using the `if-else` loop?

Thanks.
Shivam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like what `list` variables are for.  Assuming you have all your data available, create a `list` like  `mylist <- list('A'=c(aaaa,bbbbb,ccc),'B'=c(xxxxx,yyyy,zz))` and so on, with one list element for each broker.  Then to retriev the data of interest, just `mylist$B` for broker "B" and so on.

Comment: Thanks for this approach. It is quick and easy to implement. Just a quick question. Is it possible to assign names to the actual variables? In this case the 'aaaa', 'bbbbb' etc. I'm asking this so that when accessing the variables, I can use mylist$B(VARIABLENAME), instead of mylist$B[1], mylist$B[2] etc. Because using 1,2 etc can be confusing if the number of variables are high. I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: @Shivam yes, you could create nested lists as mylist$A<−list(futures=x,option=y,S⊤=z)mylist$A <- list(futures=x,option=y,STT=z) and so on. Then `mylist$A$futures` to extract a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for a single broker and assignment to a single set of values**

Depending on volumes, I would suggest a mapping table that allows you to retrieve the corresponding variables needed in each instance.  You could then use `get` to retrieve the variable required.

Here is a short example in line with your code

```
broker<-"B"
#Setup of initial variables
aa<-1
bb<-2
#Production of your mapping table
mapping<-data.frame(broker=LETTERS[1:2],brokeragefutures=c("aa","bb"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#Use get on the corresponding variable name for the broker
brokeragefutures<-get(mapping[mapping$broker==broker,2])
```